# Xamarin Forms app showing blank screen on Android when build with Azure Devops

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, yaml, devops

I'm using Azure Devops to build my Xamarin App. It produces an APK as output which I can successfully install on my device the only problem I have is that the app launches on a blank screen instead of showing me the login screen.

Is there any way to debug this issue? Strange enough this does not occur when launching in the app in Release mode on my device (using the same keystore).

I tried disabling Fast deployment in application settings in Visual Studio but to no avail.

If you need me to post my .yml file let me know.

Comment: add some logging to your app so you can see what it is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app started working after enabling zipalign under “Android signing” in Azure Devops. Weird. I didn’t think that option which is disabled by default could cause this issue.